# Need help saving the current URL as a variable

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am relatively new to Selenium IDE and very green when it comes to scripting/coding.

What I'm looking to do, from what research I've already done, is the same thing as the storeLocation command used to do.  I need to pull in the URL of the current page as a variable for use down the line.

95% of the research I've done ends up in an article from years back talking about storeLocation which is not available in the current version of IDE.

Is there another command that I can use?  Otherwise, a script I can use in IDE to save the current URL to a variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: My most successful command looks like this:  Command: execute script | Target: window.location.href | currentURL   the result is a successful test, but the variable always spits out 'undefined' so my script is probably the issue.

Comment: Be sure to edit your question and put all relevant info (like the current command) in the question itself so future readers don't have to read all the comments to get everything they need to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You was right, when use `execute script` command. But you should read [documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/#execute-script). This command just executes code that you have written in the `Target` field and doesn't return anything.

So you should use this command: `execute script | return window.location.href; | url`